# For a Computer Science major would it be beneficial to obtain a Comptia Security Plus Certificate.

Tags: software-industry, career-development, certification

So, I'm a recent Computer Science graduate and landed my first job as an ASP.NET  application developer in the government sector. I've been working here for about a year now and i'm liking the job so far and i'm getting to that point to where I want to start looking into educationally pursuits to advance my career. Due to the environment I work in the Security plus cert is seen as the goto cert to get and while I know it's popular as someone who mostly likes programming and wants to eventually get into AI among some other disciplines i'm not sure if it's worth the time investment. Do Application Development/Software development jobs usually require Security plus or is the strictly for IT?

Note: I also have some PL/SQL experience too and while I know that comes with it's on set of security related practices does the knowledge presented in Security plus help enhance this?

Comment: that entirely depends on exactly where you work and what they want

Comment: @SaggingRufus Yea, had a feeling that this question might be too broad was mostly looking for insight into rather this was something often looked for for software developers, but i get there's quite a few factors to consider. With that said thanks for commenting.

Comment: My employer pays for all software engineers to take it so that they understand the basic security fundamentals.

Comment: The best way for you to find the answer to this question would probably be to compare what the certificate would teach you and what you want to do in a job and see how closely those match up. Look at job descriptions that match your ideal role and see how many of them mention the certificate or have requirements relating to the certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Certification is always beneficial to have. Knowledge in general is useful. But the fact that your employer pays for this specific one means that it is a boost to have.

Unsure what you mean by 'time investment' being an issue, it's not your time, it would be the employers. CompTIA certs are the starting ones, not difficult to get, there isn't a significant investment and they do give a solid overview.

Comment: I get where your coming from but my employer does not pay for the cert. If I was to pursue it, it would just be on my time.

Comment: Well comptia isn't really for pure devs, it's mostly geared towards basic engineering/networking